# Calculate road index in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am following this article to obtain the road index: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S259000562200090X#bib7

The way they calculate the road index using Sentinel-2 images is by following this equation:

```
1- (3* min(B11,B8,B2)/(B11+B8+B2))
```

I am wondering how I add this index as a  band to an Image of Sentinel-2 using GEE. I already resampled the bands to the same spatial resolution.
The code I am doing is the following:

```
def calculateRI(image):
  road_bands = image.select(['B11','B8','B2'])
  Bsum = road_bands.reduce('sum')
  Bmin = road_bands.reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
  equation = ee.Image().expression('1 - (3*B / BSum)',{
      'BSum': Bsum,
      'B': Bmin}).rename('RI')
  
  new_image = image.addBands(equation)
  return new_image
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: You can use Map.addLayer() and the Inspection tool to check if you're getting the results you expect for a handful of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost correct, but you need to specify the bands you want to add to the new image. Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
def calculateRI(image):
    road_bands = image.select(['B11','B8','B2'])
    Bsum = road_bands.reduce('sum')
    Bmin = road_bands.reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
    equation = ee.Image().expression('1 - (3*B / BSum)',{
        'BSum': Bsum,
        'B': Bmin}).rename('RI')
    
    new_image = image.addBands(equation, ['RI'])
    return new_image
```

In the last line, we specify the name of the new band as ['RI']. This will add the calculated road index as a new band with the name 'RI' to the input image.

Also, note that the reduce() method returns an Image, not a number. So, in the expression, you need to divide the minimum of the three bands by the sum of the three bands, not by the sum of the reduced bands. Your corrected code should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! Considering what you said about the **reduce()** method, I am not sure If I am doing it correctly. So If I do `BSum = image.expression('B11+B8+B2').rename('BSum')`, this is correct? Do I also need to change the way to get the min of the three bands?